# Error debajo de la ultima comilla luego de la palabra diferencia

Tags: python

```
print(f"el numero ingresado es menor a 17 y la diferencia es: {diferencia}")
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

¿Por qué me dice que esta mal la ultima comilla luego de la palabra diferencia?

Comment: A veces este tipo de errores es causado por un error que está lineas más arriba, como que te olvidaste de cerrar un parentesis. Revisaste si hay algún error de sintaxis , algo sin cerrar o una mala indentación lineas más arriba?

Comment: El código publicado no tiene errores.

Comment: Dije eso por lo que dijo Candid Moe, el código publicado no tiene errores más allá de que diferencia no esté definido. Ni un solo error de sintaxis en el código publicado.

Comment: Logré reproducir el error!!! Los f-strings fueron agregados en la versión 3.6 si no me equivoco. Probé un código que usa f-strings en Python 3.5 y me dió un error similar al tuyo. Conclusión: estás usando un Python en el cual aun no existen los f-strings.

Comment: y como reemplazo los f-strings???

Comment: Haz una simple concatenación `"bla bla bla " + diferencia`. Recuerda que `diferencia` debe ser un string, si no lo es deberás convertirlo a string

Comment: Una simple busqueda en google me arrojó esta pagina con una lista de formas de formatear cadenas: https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/formato-de-cadenas-en-python-ejemplos-de-formato-s-sprint-en-python/. Es mejor usar esto que la concatenación de cadenas.

Comment: Si es python <= 3.5 usa [format()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method): `print("el numero ingresado es menor a 17 y la diferencia es: {}".format(diferencia))`

Comment: Si puedes, actualiza python. Ya va por la 3.10 (enseguida 3.11) y las f-strings no son la única mejora.

Comment: gracias!
Nosotros estamos usando mumuki, probe con format() pero ahora me tira un error "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" cuando le pido al usuario que ingrese un valor:   num=int(input("ingrese un numero: "))

Comment: De nada c: Pero viendo el nuevo problema, eso me suena a que es un problema relacionado con el interprete de Python que usa mumuki, pues [la pagina que estoy usando](https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online/) para probar las lineas de tu programa me tira el mismo error tanto en la 3.5 como en la 3.9, eso no es normal (en el interprete en mi pc funciona bien). Estás seguro de que te piden usar input en ese ejercicio?

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que en la pagina, si activas la opción "interactive" el fallo no ocurre. Mumuki tiene esa opción?